# How do I move UIView to the back?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, hierarchy

I have a prototype cell with some labels and image views, all added thru Storyboard. I am trying to add a color background view behind these elements (sort of like a bubble view behind the text that is commonly used in messengers). Trying to add this bubble view through Storyboard became a nightmare because of constraints' conflicts. So I decided to add it programmatically right in the prototypeCell class:

```
let backgroundBubble = UIView()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    backgroundBubble.backgroundColor = .yellow
    backgroundBubble.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(backgroundBubble)
    let constraints = [
        backgroundBubble.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: Label.topAnchor, constant: 0),
        backgroundBubble.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: Label.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
        backgroundBubble.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: Label.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
        backgroundBubble.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: Label.trailingAnchor, constant: 0)
    ]
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
}
```

The problem is that now the bubble view is sitting in front of the content:

[image]

I tried to move it back with:

```
sendSubviewToBack(backgroundBubble)
```

but then the yellow bubbleView disappears altogether.

**How do I move the bubbleView behind the content of the prototype cell?**

Comment: Add the yellow view to the cell's `contentView`, not the cell and then send it to the back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of a cell should basically always be added to its `contentView`. In this case, you may use `contentView.insertSubview(backgroundBubble, at: 0)` to add it as the first view in the hierarchy stack